# create jar file of only one package of a project in netbeans ide

Tags: java, jar

I would create a jar of only one package belonged to my project. this package contains a main class.how can I do?

Comment: Do you want the jar to be runnable?

Comment: yes I would the jar to be runnable.I mean I have a project with many package.I would create the jar of only one package that contain main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jar documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html):

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)

...
* The input-file(s) argument is a space-separated list of one or more files that you want to include in your JAR file. 
The input-file(s) argument can contain the wildcard * symbol. If any of the "input-files" are directories, the contents of those directories are added to the JAR archive recursively.
```

So you could just specify your path as a package:

```
jar cf <jar file name> com/companyname/package/
```